# Get name(path) of application, which invoked printing

Tags: windows, printing

Is there any way to somehow hook some winapi or something like that to get application pid\name\path which invoked print job *OR* get file data, which was sent to printing without converting via driver (i.e. if I print excel table, I want to intercept XLS file, not postscript\pcl\printer stuff).

I am using redmon, and I am really missing this information for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooked [StartDoc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd145114(v=vs.85).aspxI3YQy7bNw&sig2=0-WJjzagC3ogXC8plZYOiA&cad=rjt) winapi via mhook and called [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get executable.

Comment: But that won't get you the file.

Comment: yep, but file was "plan B" if getting executable was not possible.